# Tomcat fails to execute external java program

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I am a total newbie in JSPs/Tomcat and to a large extent in Java as well. Here's what I have to do -- when a user clicks a button/visits a URL, I want to launch a Java program (which takes some command line arguments).

I can very easily do

```
Runtime.exec("C:\\Python27\\python.exe test.py")
```

OR

```
Runtime.exec("java -cp %CLASSPATH%;C:\\devprojects HelloWorld"
```

and this works fine. Where HelloWorld.class just prints "HelloWorld".

However, when I attempt a java program which takes command line arguments, the GET request just hangs doing nothing. I don't know what logs to look for or what could be wrong here. After having spent TWO days on trying various things, I am just about to give up now.

```
Runtime.exec("java -cp %CLASSPATH%;C:\\devprojects Run --username Blah --password Foo");
```

What user does Tomcat end up running this java program as? Can I make it to be Administrator? This is on Windows 2008, does UAC interfere with things?

I cannot modify the Run.class here, I HAVE to run it as is and with command line parameters.

Please advise.

Comment: This is a really bad idea. Better to create a proper servlet.

Comment: I agree it is a bad idea. This is just prototype code though until we hire someone with related experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One idea: you are relying on the default tokenization of your command line as one complete `String`, and it is not parsing the last one as you expect. Instead you should use the form of this method that takes a `String[]`, after you have chopped up the command line yourself:

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5b%5d%29)

Or, it is waiting for input from you, or waiting for you to read its output. This could explain the hang. Search the internet for the dangers of streams and `Runtime.exec()`.

Consider `ProcessBuilder` instead.

Comment: Thanks for that ProcessBuilder and String[] tip. That was ONE of the problems. The other was the subprocess spawned was throwing something on ErrorStream which the main process wasn't draining. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Remember also that you have to be sure that the executed file dont run "forever", and
if you need to pass some arguments, you could use this:

```
    static String startProcess(String command, String dir) throws IOException {
        StringBuffer ret = new StringBuffer();
        String[] comm = new String[3];
        comm[0] = COMMAND_INTERPRETER[0];
        comm[1] = COMMAND_INTERPRETER[1];
        comm[2] = command;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        try {
            //Start process
            Process ls_proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comm, null, new File(dir));
            //Get input and error streams
            BufferedInputStream ls_in = new BufferedInputStream(ls_proc.getInputStream());
            BufferedInputStream ls_err = new BufferedInputStream(ls_proc.getErrorStream());
            boolean end = false;
            while (!end) {
                int c = 0;
                while ((ls_err.available() > 0) && (++c <= 1000)) {
                    ret.append(conv2Html(ls_err.read()));
                }
                c = 0;
                while ((ls_in.available() > 0) && (++c <= 1000)) {
                    ret.append(conv2Html(ls_in.read()));
                }
                try {
                    ls_proc.exitValue();
                    //if the process has not finished, an exception is thrown
                    //else
                    while (ls_err.available() > 0)
                        ret.append(conv2Html(ls_err.read()));
                    while (ls_in.available() > 0)
                        ret.append(conv2Html(ls_in.read()));
                    end = true;
                }
                catch (IllegalThreadStateException ex) {
                    //Process is running
                }
                //The process is not allowed to run longer than given time.
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() - start > MAX_PROCESS_RUNNING_TIME) 
//this is very important
{
                    ls_proc.destroy();
                    end = true;
                    ret.append("!!!! Process has timed out, destroyed !!!!!");
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            ret.append("Error: " + e);
        }
        return ret.toString();
    }
```